# Error when importing Android library

Tags: android, shared-libraries

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

I am trying to use this library.

But I can't successfully use the Sample

1. Import sample
2. copy lib files (except manifest, build)

But the Sample still has an error at `NumberPicker.java`

I mean All(ever) `R.` giving an error, something like `R.id.np_decrement`, `R.attr.numberPickerStyle`, `R.integer.np_config_longAnimTime`...

Comment: Please post a code sample and your exact errors. Are you referencing it as a library project, or did you copy it into your program? Also, did you reference the `NineOldAndroids` library that is mentions?

Comment: Yes I send E-mail to project-owner.

Comment: and NineOldAndroids lib include as .jar in lib forder.

Comment: and I found more specific error R.attr.*****, R.string.**** R.integer.***, R.id.**** is not working // I think they are difine as .xml in Forder value   // and they are Automatically add to R.attr.***, and inteager and string...// But they aren`t Automatically add and it going to error.  //how can i solove this problem?

Comment: Please post your `NumberPicker.java` file and your exact error message and line number. It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: It means the resources object (R.java) isn't being generated because of an error. Did you add the required attributes to your theme? Also, what is your target API version? It should be 15 or higher.

Comment: um,,, my api level is android 2.2 and Do i something to theme.xml? //I think that is a key! // What i doing in theme.xml??

Comment: Your `targetSdkVersion` should be set to 15 in your manifest. You should also have `theme.xml` from the `res/values` folder copied to the same location in your own project.

Comment: I try but nothing change...  //and On eclipse even Sample in lib is not working...  // project owner said see Sample  // But sample is not working... // NOW I take seminar so... I upload my whole code after 1.5hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources object (R.java) isn't being generated because of an error. Your `targetSdkVersion` should be set to at least 15 in your manifest, and you should also have `theme.xml` from the library's `res/values` folder copied to the same location in your own project.

Comment: Yes, it is. You need to import both the library and the sample into the workspace at the same time, it won't work without either one. I think the error you're getting is R being unable to generate due to referencing values in the library, that it can't find because it's not in the workspace.

Comment: um ....i scucess to use Sample and almost sucess apply to my App... It work but there are no imeage show....   // i think mistake is Theme.xml  // project owner says "it require 4 attributes..." I think 4attributes is item in theme.xml it is right?

Comment: Yes, it requires you to copy theme.xml to your own project.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way
1st [Download that project file](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/archive/master.zip)
2nd Open the archive and you will see one folder with name **android-numberpicker-master** extract it to your hard driver
3rd In eclipse goto File -> Import and under Android tab select **Existing Code into workspace**[image: Dialog Box]

and import both the projects
NOTE: Both the projects must be in same folder 
4th Right click on properties and goto android tab and see if project exists or add it [image]

If the library and project are not in same folder then it will throw error, so both have to be in same folder

and now try to run it and it will work

Comment: I follow your order(? step? anyway...) // after add library the message pop-up // the message is <--An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update". Path must include project and resource name: /library-->

Comment: The instead of importing create a new project and copy paste those files in that project, OR you can also try creating a new workspace

Answer (score 0):

First check out the sample application provided by the developer.

1. Right Click in your package explorer. Select Import. Select "Import existing Android Code into Workspace".
2. Browse to samples directory and import.
3. Similarly import Library and make it is marked as Library and other project is referencing  it correctly.
4. Make sure JDK compliance is set to 1.6 and your project is targeted against SDK 15 i.e 4.0.3.